# Is there a firefox equivalent to -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;?

Tags: css

Basically a web font I am using is displaying too bold in Firefox. I used the above code to fix it in webkit browsers. `-moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;`  does not work. So now I am asking all of you if there is another solution I am simply overlooking.

Note: Regardless of being an `h1` or not the font still displays too bold.

relevant code:

```
@font-face {    
  font-family: 'GelatoScript';
  src: url('../fonts/gelatoscript/gelatoscript.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/gelatoscript/gelatoscript.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('../fonts/gelatoscript/gelatoscript.woff') format('woff'),
       url('../fonts/gelatoscript/gelatoscript.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('../fonts/gelatoscript/gelatoscript.svg#GelatoScript') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

h1.pale {
  color: #f6ff96;
  font-family: 'GelatoScript';
  font-weight: 100; 
  font-size: 3.5em;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-shadow: .042em .042em 0px #787878;
}

<h1 class="pale" >Check this out!</h1>
```

Comment: It would be a good idea to stop doing that and read why here: http://usabilitypost.com/2012/11/05/stop-fixing-font-smoothing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The article Dennis Traub links to in the (previously) accepted answer is in regards to anti-aliasing for WebGL and has nothing to do with font smoothing. The simple answer to the question is: No.

**Update:** Firefox now supports `-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;` which works in basically the same way as `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;`.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this article](http://www.tomshardware.com/news/mozilla-firefox-10-aurora-silent-update-webgl,13988.html), Firefox 10 will be the first version that implements anti-aliasing.